Can a PPT adversary distinguish these two distributions of triples?
As a general premise, we have the following prerequisites:

A matrix $A\in \mathbb{F}_{q^m}^{a\times b}$ is called homogeneous of weight $t$ if the $\mathbb{F}_q$-span of the $A_{ij}$ form a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_q$ dimension $t$.
A matrix $B\in \mathbb{F}_{q^m}^{a\times b}$ is called semihomogeneous of weight $w$ if the $\mathbb{F}_q$-span of the coefficients of each row form a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_q$ dimension $w$. Note that different rows could "live" in different subspaces.
$G$ is a full rank matrix computationally indistinguishable from random.
$W = [W_1, W_2]$ is a  randomly drawn matrix, where $W_1$ is semihomogeneous of weight $w$ and $W_2$ is invertible and semihomogeneous of weight $w$.
We work in the rank metric


Consider the following two distributions:
$\mathcal{D}_1$ consists of the elements $(P, S, E)$, where

$P\leftarrow\mathbb{F}_{q^m}^{N\times (n+L)}$ is drawn uniformly
$E$ is homogeneous of weight $r$ such that $WP^T = WE^T$ (this is possible due to some trapdoor function).
$S$ is the solution of $SG = P-E$.

$\mathcal{D}_2$ consists of the elements $(P ', S ', E ')$, where

$S$ is drawn uniformly
$E$ is drawn uniformly from the space of all homogeneous matrices of weight $t$.
$P = SG + E$

Can a PPT adversary distinguish these two distributions (one can also assume that the rank support learning problem is hard)?
To my understanding, the question boils down to the equivalent question whether one can distinguish
$\mathcal{D}_1 ': (P,E)$,  $P$ uniform, $E$ uniform from all homogeneous matrices of weight $t$ from
$\mathcal{D}_2 ': (P ', E  ')$,  $P$ uniform, $E$ such that $WP^T = WE^T$.
But I cannot work out how to proceed here.

Maybe, the procedure of finding $E$ is relevant, it is obtained by using the decoder $\Phi(W, WP^T)$ from here, Chapter 4. The error probability of a decoding failure is also given there.

